# How to run an applescript when a print window pops up?

Tags: pdf, printing, applescript

I have to save many htmls as pdfs. When a print window pops up, I manually click options for saving pdfs. I want to automate this task by applescript. But I don't know how to run an applescript when a print window pops up?

[image]

Comment: Why not just save your print preferences to use those settings by default and then choose that setting? Why involve Applescript at all?

Comment: I also use my print preference. But I have to do the same job manually many times almost over 100 times. So I want to automate the job.

Comment: You can use Applescript to press buttons in a dialog, but it's kind of messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions on this page:

https://superuser.com/questions/257290/how-to-record-a-macro-that-saves-web-pages-as-pdf-in-osx

Not sure if this will work for you, but it's probably a start.

Comment: I uploaded an image in my question.
I can't find how to control presets of the print dialog by applescript.

Comment: What presets do you actually need to select? Exporting a PDF has nothing to do with printing. Please be more specific about your goals and then we might be able to help you.

Comment: Because I have to set a paper size of pdf, so I want to know how to set a preset of the print dialog automatically. I use some application, After I selected a preset of the application, always the preset of the application turn back to default preset on next time.

Comment: I solved the problem on my own. Here is [my code](https://gist.github.com/neosarchizo/1a8098371fc731c97c09ad76389df01f). 
After I used a printer on the mac, the preset is not changed. I think that because there was not available printer, so the preset had been changed.